# Getting the float value of NSNumber object crashes iPhone 6 devices exclusively

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsnumber

I am developing an iOS app that involves fetching an NSNumber object from Core Data persistent store and read the float value of that object into memory. The code is as follows:

```
    let settingItemsFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MTSettings")
    print(uid)
    let currentUser = ConvenientMethods.getCurrentUser(uid)

    let predicateForFetchingSettingsOfSpecificUser = NSPredicate(format: "(belongTo == %@)", argumentArray: [currentUser])
    settingItemsFetchRequest.predicate = predicateForFetchingSettingsOfSpecificUser

    var settingsOfCurrentUser : [MTSettings]? = nil
    var settingOfCurrentUser : MTSettings? = nil

    do {
        settingsOfCurrentUser = try managedObjectContextInUse.executeFetchRequest(settingItemsFetchRequest) as? [MTSettings]
        settingOfCurrentUser = settingsOfCurrentUser!.last
    } catch {
        fatalError("An error has occurred: Failed to fetch setting items from the database.")
    }

    let currentFontSizeInRawValue = settingOfCurrentUser!.desiredFontSize!.floatValue
    let currentFontInRawValue = settingOfCurrentUser!.desiredFont! as String
```

Everything works just fine in simulators, so I archived the build and uploaded to iTunes Connect. The internal testing team installed this build via TestFlight service on their own devices and this weird bug happens: all the iPhone 6 devices are crashing while the iPhone 6S devices run the app just fine. I collected the bug reports from TestFlight and it says:

[Screenshot of the crash organizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZOx0.jpg)

I checked the faulty line of code in stack 0 and it is

```
let currentFontSizeInRawValue = settingOfCurrentUser!.desiredFontSize!.floatValue
```

I really cannot figure out the root of the problem. Why are iPhone 6 devices crashing? Does iPhone 6S run this line of code differently under the hood? How should I fix it?

Comment: I would like to add that all the testing devices are running iOS 9.3.5.

Comment: You have two "!" in there, so it's a bit hard to tell which might be causing the problem. One is bound to be unexpectedly nil.

Comment: I see. But what really bothers me is that iPhone 6S devices run the code just fine (get the right value, no error/warning reported). Only iPhone 6 devices crashed.

Comment: Have you tried multiple iPhone 6's and seen the crash in all of them?

Comment: Yeah. Tried it on 3 iPhone 6 and 2 iPhone 6 Plus. All crashed.

Comment: If you get to the root cause of the crash it might explain why it's occuring on one group and not others. Maybe there is alternatively a coincidence of all the users with an iPhone 6, so it's actually the user, not the phone.